# Proxy service Wso2 - Service Deployed Time

Tags: web-services, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have noticed that the "service deployed time" of a proxy service and the "System Up time" of the wso2esb it's different.

If my proxy service is deployed when I start wso2esb, why the times are different?

In my case:

```
Server Start Time   2013-10-30 13:11:17 
System Up Time  15 day(s)  19 hr(s)  45 min(s)  13 sec(s) 

Service Deployed Time   2013-11-15 05:13:12
Service Up Time     3hr(s) 45min(s)
```

The difference between the start time and the deployed time is very big. No reboots has been done. Why has my proxy service been deployed without my knowledge?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the configuration changes you have done in WSO2 ESB? Have you enabled deployment synchronizer? Have you deployed you services in super-tenant? I didn't go through this, but just asking to check.

Comment: I haven't configurated anything. I've installed wso2esb by default.